# FirebaseAuth Exceptions debugging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a question about `FirebaseAuth` which I'm not so experienced with,

I'm doing sign-in using `E-mail` and `Password` and I want to debug the error, but I found 2 options.

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password):

addOnCompleteListener and check if task is not successful (!task.isSuccessful())
or 
addOnCompleteListener and addOnFailureListener
```

Which one is better and why?

Comment: Yea i know that i can use both but why should i add 2 Listeners this may lead to performance issue or something due to much listeners,
I think if condition is better approach but is it really better or the FailureListener has some advantages?

Comment: Both approaches can accomplish the exact same things. Neither one of them is better than the other. Which one you use is a combination of personal preference and the use-case you're looking to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, you should use `addOnCompleteListener` as you can get both success and failure events with this listener but you can use both of them at the same time if you have any doubt

```
databaseReference.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        //failure
                    }
                    else {
                        //success
                    }
                }
            })
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Yea i can use both but why should i add 2 Listeners this may lead to performance issue or something due to much listeners,
I think if condition is better approach but is it really better or the FailureListener has some advantages?

Answer (score 1):

actually both of the methods are useful in their ways if you want to get the correct error code the implement onFailureListener or else onComplete listener does the work but it doesnt gives you the error code

Comment: So the diff in the error code not in performance or specific usage?

Comment: no onCompleteListener is called every time even if task is not successful but onFailureListener is called only when task is failed